# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: c#, mysql

Please help me out from this error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Line 48:     {
Line 49:     }
Line 50:     public OwUser(Decimal p_id): base(p_id)
Line 51:     {
Line 52:     }

Source File:  c:\MyWork\Projects\80. Minerva\01. Api\OwMinerva\Code\Domain\Generated\OwUserPart.cs    Line:  50

Stack Trace:

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
   OwDatabase.OwConnection.InitializeConnections() in c:\MyWork\Projects\02. Core\01. Api\OwCore\Code\Database\Constants\Utility\OwConnection.cs:119
   OwDatabase.OwConnection.get_DBConnection() in c:\MyWork\Projects\02. Core\01. Api\OwCore\Code\Database\Constants\Utility\OwConnection.cs:191
   OwDatabase.OwDBObject.PrimaryMatching(String p_tableName) in c:\MyWork\Projects\02. Core\01. Api\OwCore\Code\Database\Object Map\OwDBObject.cs:1423
   OwDatabase.OwDBObject.PrimaryMatching() in c:\MyWork\Projects\02. Core\01. Api\OwCore\Code\Database\Object Map\OwDBObject.cs:1409
   OwDatabase.OwDBDescribedObject..ctor(Decimal p_id) in c:\MyWork\Projects\02. Core\01. Api\OwCore\Code\Database\Object Map\OwDBDescribedObject.cs:50
   Ow.OwUser..ctor(Decimal p_id) in c:\MyWork\Projects\80. Minerva\01. Api\OwMinerva\Code\Domain\Generated\OwUserPart.cs:50
   OwUI.OwConfiguration.BindApplicationClientCodition(OwDBObject baseObject) in c:\MyWork\Projects\80. Minerva\MinervaAspxUI\MinervaAspxUI\Classes\OwConfiguration.cs:120
   OwUI.OwSearchPage.BindData(String sortField, OwDBObject finder, Boolean fromSearch, OwDBObject minObject) in c:\MyWork\Projects\80. Minerva\MinervaAspxUI\MinervaAspxUI\Classes\OwSearchPage.cs:254
   OwUI.OwSearchPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\MyWork\Projects\80. Minerva\MinervaAspxUI\MinervaAspxUI\Classes\OwSearchPage.cs:180
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498

Comment: Your database isn't configured correctly.

Comment: So, you're getting an exception message when connecting to [tag:mysql]? You ought to make that more explicit in the question. But, what do you want *us* to do about it? We don't know anything *except* the exception message.

Comment: The user account in your MySQL database has not been set up the same way that you are using it.

Comment: Share your code with us.

Comment: If your adding users through phpmyadmin,can you show the user you are trying to connect to the server with.

Comment: Are database and application hosted on the same machine?

Comment: Database and application hosted in the same machine..

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that your password is not correct or you haven't configured the user account correctly. You can read more about creating user accounts [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html).

Also, maybe you're not connecting to the right server (As you are now connecting to the `localhost` mysql database).

In `'root'@'localhost'` the `root` is the user account you're trying to log in with and the `localhost` is your local mysql server host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added new user &  tried that method also still it is giving same error, could u explain any other reasons for this error

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings when you start your mysql service?